# Modules in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
module Hints
 module Designer
  def message
   "Hello, World!"
  end
 end
end

p Hints::Designer.message
```

Why this give me the following error...?

*undefined method `message' for Hints::Designer:Module (NoMethodError)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is define message as a class method (not as an instance method). Try:

```
module Hints
 module Designer
  def self.message
   "Hello, World!"
  end
 end
end

puts Hints::Designer.message
```

If you want to use instance methods with a module, you must extend an object using the module and any given constraints (see http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use this:

```
module Hints
 module Designer
  def self.message
   "Hello, World!"
  end
 end
end
```

That is, make `message` a "class" method (before it was an instance method). This seems a bit weird, but keep in mind that modules are often used to create mixin classes, so an "instance of a module" makes sense in that context.

Answer (score 1):

use `p Hints::Designer.new.message`

message is an instance method not a class method

Comment: sry, that only works if `Designer` is a Class, I didn't read the whole text carefully, my eyes saw what they were used to see ... http://codepad.org/AZ5TaShz